# The procedure entry point _ZNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, stdstring

I am having immense difficulty trying to use std::string. The program compiles absolutely fine, but when I run the program, I receive this error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3UN7.png)

I have looked everywhere on google and haven't found a thing on how to solve this issue. I have also tried writing my code differently to see if that would tell me anything.

```
std::string yourName;
std::cout << "What is your name?";
std::cin >> yourName;
std::cout << "Hello, " << yourName << std::endl;
```

Despite the rewrite, I am still getting the same exact error, and I am not forgetting to include the iostream and string header files.

I am using the GCC compiler and my compile code is **g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test.exe**. I have also tried using the compile code **g++ test.cpp -o test.exe**. This did not fix the error.

I have asked this question before on Stack Overflow, but I failed to get a clear and understandable answer, most likely due to the fact that I am a complete beginner in programming. That being said, can someone please give me an answer on what might be causing this problem and how to fix it in *plain English*?

Comment: The program is not loading the correct DLL, at runtime. Why that happens, that's something you will need to figure out yourself. Amongst everyone who is currently logged on on stackoverflow.com, there's only one person who knows what DLLs are installed on your computer, or where (that would be you, of course). The error is because the program gets linked with one version of the C++ runtime DLL, but ends up trying to load a different DLL at runtime. This answers the question of what this error means. You'll have to figure out why, by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded GCC from this link: [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64) and reinstalled GCC. My problems were successfully fixed.

Comment: After you installed from the link, did you add "yourinfohere"MinGW/bin to the path?

Comment: Yes, you need to update your system PATH to the one located at the install folder. This finally worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
g++ <file> -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

I had the same problem, but it worked for me

Comment: For me it worked ! xD