# C++ : Procedure entry point couldn't be located

Tags: c++, string, mingw

I'm making a simple program with C++ where I'm reading input to a C++ string and output it as the equivalent C string.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test;
    cin >> test;

    cout << test.c_str();

    return 0;
}
```

I can compile the program without any errors or warnings, but when I execute it I get this error:

```
The procedure entry point _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE5c_strEv could not be located in the dynamic link library
```

I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the code so I can't really understand what is happening..

I'm using Windows with MinGW (g++ version 5.3.0) and this is how I'm compiling the program:
`g++ -Wall test.cpp -o test`

Can somebody help here?

Comment: What does `g++ --version` output? Are you able to compile programs with C++ strings, but without SDL? Also, how does a complete program looks like? (With all includes and the `main()`.)

Comment: Apparently not, I just got the same error while executing a simple program with strings and no SDL. Interesting, this is the first time this happens to me. G++ version is 5.3.0 @HolyBlackCat

Comment: If it's not because of SDL, then you should edit the question accordingly, removing any info about SDL, and adding the 'simple program with strings' that you've just tried instead.

Comment: Properly updated, thanks @HolyBlackCat

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738610/the-procedure-entry-point-znst7-cxx1112basic-stringlcst11char-traitslcesalceec1). It suggests to just update to the latest MinGW.

Comment: When re-installing while selecting only what I thought to be the necessary packages the error persisted. Anyway, using the installer provided in the link you sent did the work. Thanks! Should I mark this as a duplicate question to the one you sent or answer it myself? @HolyBlackCat